# Regex to parse out IP next to a set value

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to parse out an IP address next to a value from a html code. In the html code it looks like this:
example

X_Value_B: 192.12.21.31

So I want to be able to check what Ip is given next to the X_Value_B:

How would i parse this out?

This is what I have so far:

```
Match m = Regex.Matche(_respStr1, @"\b(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

However this does not grab the Ip specifically next to the X_Value_B:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one:

```
var match = Regex.Match(inputString, 
                    @"X_Value_B:\s*(?<ip>\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)");

if(match .Success)
    String strIp = match.Groups["ip"].Value;
```

Comment: you get exception if don't match

Comment: @burning_LEGION: yes. but this is out of your question scope. i updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

use lookbehind `(?<=)` f.e. `(?<=X_Value_B:\s*)(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}`

Comment: Thanks! Will do green check in 4 mins when i can :) Again, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting you right, what you need is

```
(?!X_Value_B:\s)\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}
```

That'll extract

```
192.12.21.31
```

From

```
X_Value_B: 192.12.21.31
```